# Disable jquery mobile in non touch devices for swipe

Tags: jquery-mobile

In one of our application we wanted to have a swipe behavior for tablet so we added jQuery mobile ui for that . In result the swipe worked for non touch devices as well. Now few days after we realised that it is causing pain to users and now we wants to stop it for desktop but available for tablet . Is there a way in Api to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post js code for swipe?

Comment: Hi Prashant, did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue